# Strange Google Apps Script Gmail Behaviour

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

Hoping someone can help me solve this:

I recently wrote a script to label all items in my trash folder on a trigger basis (hourly), move them to the archive so that they are removed from the trash. However, occasionally the numbers do not add up and there are 5-10 additional emails added to my new label that were not accounted for in my trash folder.

Is there a better approach than below:

```
function DeletedArchive() {


//
var myLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("DeletedArchive");
  for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {


var threads = GmailApp.getTrashThreads(0, 100);
Logger.log('Trash threads: ' + threads);
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
Logger.log('Trash threads: ' + threads[i]);
    threads[i].addLabel(myLabel);
    Logger.log('Trash threads with label applied: ' + threads[i]);
    threads[i].moveToArchive();
    Logger.log('Trash threads moved: ' + threads[i]);
};


};
}
```

Comment: If you add some `Logger.log('text here: ' + variableName);` statements, run the code, then view the Logs, and show us the Logs.

Comment: Have I applied it correctly? I can send the execution transcript?

Comment: Here is the log: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MWr7YPXPhba1iKr1ldwPZziy_HuG91ihoUHjw1_pYy8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Because the issue is a count difference, I would log the length: `Logger.log('threads length: ' + threads.length);` And then log each counter:  `Logger.log('i: ' + i);`  I'd also log the `getFirstMessageSubject()`  Like so:  `message subject: ' + threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject());` Then look for differences in the actual emails and the logged information to determine which emails are the ones involved in the issue.